# How do I set up a route when I am calling other functions in my App.jsx file in my static react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have tried moving the `BrowserRouter` from `react-router-dom` from my `main.jsx` file to my `App.jsx` file but it does not work.

This is what I have in my App.jsx:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <PageHeader />
      <About />
      <Works />
      <Contact />
      <Footer />

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/resume" element={<Resume />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}
```

It just shows up on the same page as my other components when I want it as if it is a separate page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently all the content content *other than* `Resume` is unconditionally rendered. If you would like it to also be *conditionally* rendered then move the content into a route.

Example:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/"
        element={(
          <>
            <PageHeader />
            <About />
            <Works />
            <Contact />
            <Footer />
          </>
        )}
      />
      <Route path="/resume" element={<Resume />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

If you want each page to render with the header and footer then these can be moved out of the routes to be unconditionally rendered.

Example:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <PageHeader />
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={(
            <>
              <About />
              <Works />
              <Contact />
            </>
          )}
        />
        <Route path="/resume" element={<Resume />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```